# Tool for Developing SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssms, management-studio-express

I only have SSMS 2008 Express on my dev machine.  What tools are there that I can use to develop, maintain, and manage server side SSRS reports on this machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need BIDS - Business Intelligence Development Studio, which is the Visual Studio shell for developing reports that target SQL Reporting Services, and is included as part of Reporting Services install.

You can download SQL Express with Advanced Services [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e08766ce-fc9d-448f-9e98-fe84ad61f135). This version of SQL Express includes Reporting Services.

Comment: would you know of a tool which can be used to mass upload/update reports from Server1 to Server 2-8? We have 8 environment, and when there is a new reports or changes gets made to current report, we want to synchronize that change across all servers.

Comment: @VoodooChild I don't know of a commercially available tool to do that, we created our own - reports are shipped in a zip file and our utility unzips it and uploads the reports to the target server (it's a relatively straightforward utility to make).

Comment: I've read on SO that some folks here have used RSBuild for uploading reports (http://rsbuild.codeplex.com/) - have you any experience in that? Does it seems different than your in-house tool? FYI, I am not a SSRS expert and am just looking at way to simplifying the deployment process, any suggestion/comments?

Comment: @VoodooChild Yeah that looks like an alright tool, very similar to ours (but ours was a WPF desktop app, so we had nice progress bars and stuff). RSBuild should do a fairly good job and have a fairly established way of using it, if you needed to build something more sophisticated then you can use it as a template or just build a UI over top of it.

Answer (score 0):

sqlserver express may have some sp things. there's one tool is for ssrs development. you can check it out.

Comment: what do you mean by "sp things"?